# How To Update Xcode 5 DP

Tags: ios, xcode5

How to update Xcode 5 DP without downloading a new release from apple's website, I mean update from app store or directly update from the current Xcode 5 DP. Thank You!

Comment: No way. DPs do not hit app store. Xcode does not include update functionality either. And this is not a programming questions.

Comment: I had this same question.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: So for anyone else lost and confused like me, you simply open Xcode and it will update itself.  At least mine did.

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge and work there is no chance of updating . Only option we have is we have to download the xcode 5 Dp and install .

Answer (score 1):

It's beta release and isn't connected yet with the mac App Store. Apple make it a separate partition so you could use it and in-parralel use the stable Xcode version.

Therefore there is no option to update without downloading the new file. Don't forget to delete the old one.

Good luck!